# Условия if/else в pug

Tags: html5, jade, pug

Есть блок с `svg` и нужно менять содержимое в зависимости от переменной, код:

```
mixin container(svg)    
.logo-box
    if svg == first
      svg.class__first
    else if svg === second
      svg.class__second
    else if svg === third
      svg.class__third
    else
      svg.class__fourth
+container(first)
+container(second)
+container(third)
```

Проблема заключается в том, что неважно какое значение я пишу в миксине `container()` всегда отображается `svg.class__first`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Синтаксис pug](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html), вроде как, гласит что нужны кавычки.

```
mixin container(svg)    
  .logo-box
      if svg=='first'
        svg.class__first
      else if svg=='second'
        svg.class__second
      else if svg=='third'
        svg.class__third
      else
        svg.class__fourth


+container('first')
+container('second')
+container('third')
```

[Пример на CodePen](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/ajBaGd?editors=1000) (View Compiled HTML)

Comment: было б неплохо пояснение почему это работало именно так без кавычек :-)

Comment: @Grundy, Синтаксис такой, наверное))) , а есть где-нибудь описание почему, например, в js\jq пишется так: `function F(variable) { .... } F('my variable')` ....

Comment: В спецификации описано :-) плюс никто не мешает написать `F(variable)`

Answer (score 1):

Небольшое дополнение к соседнему ответу.

Код в pug является обычным кодом javascript.

Без кавычек `first`, `second`, `third` считаются переменными и, так как они нигде не объявлены, их значением будет `undefined`.

Убедиться в этом можно добавив следующее условие:

```
if(typeof(first) == 'undefined')
  +container(first)
```

И в этом случае будет выведено всего два блока.

Так как все переменные равны `undefined`, и передаются тоже, то вполне работает равенство `undefined === undefined`.

Для исправления можно воспользоваться решением из соседнего ответа: отказаться от переменных и использовать строки.

Либо объявить переменные и присвоить им нужные значения.

Comment: Спасибо! И мне, весьма, полезно будет знать!)